# Does a UART connection require shared ground?

Tags: serial, uart, pi-pico

I'm a novice with electronics but not Linux. This situation has had me scratching my head for two nights.

I connected a Pi Pico to a Raspberry Pi 4 via UART, and managed to receive messages sent from the Pico on the Pi successfully. The Pico was connected to my PC via USB; the Pi was connected to a power supply. Then I busied myself with other parts of the project. When I came back, and for many hours, I simply could not get the serial connection to work. Either I received serial 'noise' in `picocom`, or nothing at all.

Finally, I supplied juice to the Pico directly through the Pi via the Pi's GPIO, and disconnected the Pico from my PC. Lo and behold, the UART worked faultlessly!

Does a UART connection *need* shared ground? It worked before, but perhaps that was a fluke? If I hadn't seen it work earlier, I wouldn't have spent hours trying to replicate the exact conditions I'd had before to get it working again!

I admit I don't really understand the principle of shared ground in the first place.

Comment: Try your original configuration with a ground connection between Pi and Pico - because yes, you should have a common ground

Comment: Ah, (1) I think if you optically isolate the Tx/Rx signals of each side (eg. Rpi and Pico), then you don't need any common ground at all. (2) Of course Tx/Rx each side has a local common ground, but the two local grounds need not be common, ie, shorted or connected together.  (3)  Actually for industrial/noisy and/or long wire/distance communication, it is a good idea to totally optically isolate all signals. (4) Eg if Rpi and Pico are powered by two separate 12V/24V stepped down to 5V) Lipo power banks, then Rpi and Pcio local ground need not be directly or indirectly connected.

Comment: (5) You might like to look at the schematic diagram of the short answer part of my TLDR answer to the following EESE Q&A: JD-Vcc Relay Problem: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry. (6) EE pros always try to use optical isolation to avoid common ground. The reason is that mains or other sources of noise/voltage spikes (eg back EMF) always travels along the common ground wiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Q: *"Does a UART connection need/require a shared ground?"*

##### A: No, it does not. UART is a communication protocol that has been successfully used in applications that prohibit the use of a shared or common ground between the terminals.

There are many examples of UART applications that do not use a shared/common ground. To cite just a couple of application areas:

1. UARTs are used in systems that require  [galvanic isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation) between its communication terminals; e.g.  [UART via opto-isolators](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uart+via+optocoupler&atb=v278-1&ia=web), and
2. in systems where the terminals may be ground-based or airborne, or separated by great distances; i.e. [they use an rf link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uart+via+rf+link).

That said, it seems clear that the vast majority of UART applications are in fact implemented as direct-connections using a shared ground. This being due to wide availability, ease of use, the physical proximity of most UART terminals, and other factors that favor simplicity over performance. The schematic below shows a typical direct connection between two  [UART](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/back-to-basics-the-universal-asynchronous-receiver-transmitter-uart/) terminals. ***In this case, a common, shared ground is required.***

[image]

However, there are many situations where a shared ground is difficult or undesirable; e.g. when [galvanic isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation) is required between the two circuits, or when the [signal-to-noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) falls below that required for reliable communication.

For these situations, the shared ground may be - or must be - eliminated. In a high noise environment, or if galvanic isolation is required, there are a [wide variety of available solutions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uart+via+optocoupler) that utilize transformers or optocouplers or current loops that eliminate the shared ground. When physical distance is the issue, r[f-based solutions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uart+via+rf+link) are available to transfer uart signals.

[This Application Note from Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/80151/opticalisolatorrs232.pdf) provides a detailed description of the implementation of an opto-coupled interconnection between 2 UART terminals that do not share a common ground. The figure below (from the app note) shows two separate supplies (Vcc1 & Vcc2), and two separate grounds (GND1 & GND2).

[image]

Note that the circuit shown above remains a UART connection. We have added or altered the [*physical layer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer), but the [UART protocol](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/back-to-basics-the-universal-asynchronous-receiver-transmitter-uart/) and its hardware realization is in the [*data link layer* (Layer 2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) remains unchanged. Any software layers or additional processing that occurs in layers 3 - 7 will work exactly as they did before. And so it follows that the need for a common or shared ground in a UART-based comm application depends upon the physical layer implementation used.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Gnd (or similar) connection in ANY CIRCUIT. That is why they are called circuits; there MUST be a complete path for current to flow.

You say your circuit works; often there are indirect paths e.g through Ethernet or USB cables etc. It is a poor practice to rely on accidental indirect paths.

Comment: Of course any circuit needs gnd to allow the current to flow. But what about two independent circuits with their own power supplies that both have their independent gnd connections. Will the uart connection work? From my experience a common ground is required.